# Debug assertion failed vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++

When this goes through for loop, I keep having error message

> "Debug assertion failed. vector subscript out of range."

so I tracked the for loop, and when input is

```
5
1 100
2 100
3 80
4 60
5 80
```

The error occurred when i == 2. But I have no idea what's wrong after i==2.
Please give me some advice.

the error is at this part:

```
for (int i = 0; i < childNum; i++) {
        if (!IncrementIfFound(value_counts, info.gram_v[i])) {
            Number_Counts temp(info.gram_v[i]);
            value_counts.push_back(temp);
            cout << "Value counts: " << value_counts[i].value << "\t" << value_counts[i].count << endl;
        }
    }
```

And this is my code :

```
struct Number_Counts
{
    int value;
    int count;
    Number_Counts( int _element) { value = _element; count = 1; }
};

struct ChildInfo
{
    vector<int> id_v;
    vector<int> gram_v;
};

bool IncrementIfFound(vector<Number_Counts> &, int );

bool IncrementIfFound(vector<Number_Counts> &_Container, int _element)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _Container.size(); i++) {
        if (_Container[i].value == _element) {
            _Container[i].count++;
            cout << "i : " << i <<" Container value: " << _Container[i].value << " counter: " << _Container[i].count 
                << " size: " << _Container.size() << endl;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    vector<Number_Counts> value_counts;
    ChildInfo info;
    int childNum,id, gram = 0;

    cin >> childNum;
    for (int i = 0; i < childNum; i++) {
        cin >> id >> gram;
        info.id_v.push_back(id);
        info.gram_v.push_back(gram);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < childNum; i++) {
        if (!IncrementIfFound(value_counts, info.gram_v[i])) {
            Number_Counts temp(info.gram_v[i]);
            value_counts.push_back(temp);
            cout << "Value counts: " << value_counts[i].value << "\t" << value_counts[i].count << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < childNum; i++) {
    if (!IncrementIfFound(value_counts, info.gram_v[i])) {
        Number_Counts temp(info.gram_v[i]);
        value_counts.push_back(temp);
        cout << "Value counts: " << value_counts[i].value << "\t" << value_counts[i].count << endl;
    }
}
```

Imagine if your `if` skips first `n` iterations. Than when you access `value_counts[i].value`, you will be accessing beyond array bounds, because new values were not added to vector.

```
        auto&& number_count = value_counts.back();
        cout << "Value counts: " << number_count.value << "\t" << number_count.count << endl;
```

Comment: Why don't simply print `temp`?

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad That is also an option is this case. But, well, in general, this options are not equal, so if OP wanted to print the object that was pushed to vector, this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Ohhhh Thanks a lot I missed it @Satus

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad sorry for rejecting I didn't know how to accept it and I accidently hit something else :(